# How to change the Transparency of an UIImage not UIImageView in iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios

How to change the Alpha or transparency of UIImage Object not UIImageView or View

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10492249/919545

Comment: You will have to start messing with the context of an image. Good if you know how to do it, pain if you don't.

Comment: @Popeye why did you remove `iPhone` and `ios` tag ?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava I think [the accepted answer of the question that you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10819117/335858) is more efficient.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes you are correct

Comment: @Hector As this is not a specific iPhone or ios question. I would have at one point added these tags as well but I was told by a moderator if they are not specific to that tag they shouldn't be added. And iPhone tag is problems with the iPhone and ios is problems with the ios which both these are not.

Comment: @Satish - Popeye is correct in that this is not iPhone specific. However, I would disagree in that it is iOS specific, so I removed only the iPhone tag.

Comment: @qegal I'm not a Mac developer but does alpha or transparency for UIImage objects not exist on OSX platforms. If not totally agree.

Comment: @Popeye - It does, but as `NSImage`. Similarly, CGRect for iOS becomes NSRect for Mac, UIView for iOS becomes NSView for Mac, etc. So since this question pertains to UIImage, it is solely iOS related.

Comment: @qegal OK thanks you learn something new everyday. I plan on taking up Mac development soon so this will help me.