# saving an image which has been changed using an alpha slider

Tags: ios, xcode, save, alpha, photo-gallery

I'm fairly new to xcode and objective c and have a problem that I think is quite simple.

I have a table view controller populated with UIImages, you touch a cell and it open the UIImage full screen in a view controller.

In the view controller i've coded an alpha slider which changes the alpha of the image (makes it more transparent) and also a save button which saves the image to your photo library.

THE PROBLEM: when the save button is pressed, it only saves the original UIImage that was in table view controller and not the altered image that has been changed by the alpha slider,

How can i get the save button to save the altered image?

I've looked on almost every post in this site but can't seem to find something this specific

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Do you really modify the `UIImage` itself? Or do you just set the `alpha` of the `UIImageView`?

Comment: I just set the alpha of the UIImageView, but I want users to be able to save the altered image

Comment: Well, the `UIImageView` is only a view component for *displaying* the image. Changing it's alpha won't change anything on the underlying `UIImage`. For that, you will probably need to draw the image via CoreGraphics. Searching SO leads to this answer, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084845/how-to-set-the-opacity-alpha-of-a-uiimage