# Change alpha value of only a part of UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, alpha

How do I change the alpha value only of a part of an UIImage in Xcode? 
[image]

Comment: Need more info. What platform, what libraries, what have you tried, and it's not an Xcode question because Xcode is just the IDE.

Comment: [How to set the opacity/alpha of a UIImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084845/how-to-set-the-opacity-alpha-of-a-uiimage)

Comment: @Almo: Thanks. I changed the key words in my question. I have a ball and I try to change the alpha value on only a part of that ball image, as shown in the attached image.

Comment: You should use alpha masking. This documentation has a lot of examples: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html

Comment: OK. I'll read about alpha masking. Thanks to all.