# how to set alpha on Backgroung image using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a button with background image and need to set the alpha to 0.5. How can I do this in swift?
This is my code that set the button background image
`centerButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "buttonImage"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to set alpha on only background image, then re-create UIImage with changing the alpha value.

if you want to set alpha to entire button, then simply set alpha value to the button.

```
centerButton.alpha = 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create UIImage instance first and change alpha, then, setBackgroundImage to your button.

You can check: [How to set the opacity/alpha of a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084845/how-to-set-the-opacity-alpha-of-a-uiimage)