# UIButton with low alpha background but fully opaque title?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I make a `UIButton` with a transparent background but a non-transparent title? I tried the following

```
button.alpha = .5;
button.titleLabel.alpha = 1;
```

That did not have the desired effect. Other suggestions?

Comment: Subclass the button and do it internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make only the background 0.5 alpha

```
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:100.0/255.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:0.5];
```

Comment: Can I do that without doing it by setting the color?

Comment: are you have background image on the button ?

Comment: you can read existing backgroundColor and create new background color out of it by keeping all the components same except alpha

Answer (score 1):

Just try playing with different parts of your button.

---

For example, if that is the image, that you want with alpha 0.5, then try this:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.imageView.alpha = 0.5;
```

---

or even this:

```
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];

button.backgroundColor = [button.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
```

---

You can even add alpha directly onto UIImage --
[How to set the opacity/alpha of a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084845/how-to-set-the-opacity-alpha-of-a-uiimage)

The above link would help if you are setting the image via:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

I don't know other solutions, though. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:
swift `button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)`