# Change opacity of parent layer without affecting child layer in Swift

Tags: swift, calayer, opacity, alpha

I have a UIImage. I am creating a CALayer and adding it to the UIImage layer. I want to change the UImage's layer opacity to 0.5 without affecting the child layer's opacity. In my research it seem snot possible. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084845/how-to-set-the-opacity-alpha-of-a-uiimage

Comment: Thanks @Naresh that fixed my problem