# Replacement of UITableViewCell.imageView.alpha on iOS14

Tags: ios, uitableview, deprecated

UITableViewCell.imageView is deprecated on iOS14.
I checked UIListContentConfiguration's properties but couldn't fine a replacement for `cell.imageView.alpha`. What should I do?

```
cell.imageView.alpha = 1f;
```

Comment: Why do you need to set `alpha` on something that shouldn't be used at all?

Comment: @Sulthan Could you explain this further? I can prepare additional images in different opacity and set to UIListContentConfiguration.image. But I wonder there is a way to do this without additional images.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem now.
Basically, if you need anything advanced, use a custom content view and add alpha to your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's no way to directly change opacity of cell's imageView anymore.
I used an extension of the UIImage class as this post suggested and it works well
[How to set the opacity/alpha of a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084845/how-to-set-the-opacity-alpha-of-a-uiimage)